# ckEditor: How to prevent HTML entity encoding fullPage mode?

Tags: ckeditor

in my ckEditor config, I have set:

```
entities: false,
basicEntities: false,
entities_greek: false,
entities_latin: false,
allowedContent: true
```

in order to prevent as much as possible entity conversion. This works as desired, unless I also enable

```
fullPage: true
```

If fullPage is set to true, basic entities get inserted as entities again, which breaks my whole setup. (I'd like to edit mustache/handlebars templates, and the partial notation uses '>': {{> partial}} --> {{&gt; partial}}.)

Is there a way to prevent html entity translation in fullPage mode?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, discovered how to add an exception via the htmlFilter:

```
ck.on('instanceReady', function() {
  this.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
    "text": function( text ) {
      return text.replace( /\{\{\s*\&gt;/, "{{>"
    }   
} );
```